# Error parsing LocalFile: 'E:\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' Please ensure that the android manifest is a valid XML document and try again

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, android-manifest, fluttermap

my application worsks perfectly fine. but when i add some uses-permission for internet and map and api key for google map it gives me error. i tried flutter clean, flutter run but still getting the same error. I dont understand what i am doing wrong in manifest file. please someone help me.

**Here is my manifest file code:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.food_order">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:label="food_order"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
       
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyCn************ratM"/>  
  
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't see the closing tag for manifest ( </manifest> ) at the end. Without it the XML is invalid. Please check that, update the question if you just copy pasted it wrong to SO.

Comment: sorry, I just copy pasted it wrong

Comment: No problem, I've posted an answer bellow, hopefully it should work for you now.

Comment: for me it was some extra bracket i was putting around the meta tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `>` after the `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, so it should be like this:

```
<application
    android:label="food_order"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

<activity...
```

Your IDE should have given you hints about this, like so
[image: IDE hint]

If you aren't using an IDE I strongly suggest you start using one :).

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes is usually because **you commented some part of code snippet in the AndroidManifest.xml out**; not knowing some other parts of the entire code is also commented out.
So I recommend you checking well to know what's actually wrong before deciding to move on with other *alternative ways* of fixing such.

Answer (score 0):

remove all spaces between `<manifest>` node and `<application>`

Like this :

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.companyname.myappname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
   <application
        android:label="My App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
```

Comment: I dont understand this answer. The xml here appears not well formed, and spaces between tags are generally innocuous in xml..